# Grails - passing hasOne relationship to form

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp

I have 2 beans:

```
class GroupVisitReconfirmation {
  int visitorsNumber
  static belongsTo = [
    groupVisitRequest: GroupVisitRequest
  ]
  static constraints = {
      visitorsNumber nullable: false, validator: { val, obj, errors ->
          def visitorsNumber = obj.groupVisitRequest.visitorsNumber
      }
  }
}

class GroupVisitRequest extends VisitRequest {
  static hasOne = [
    groupVisitReconfirmation: GroupVisitReconfirmation
  ]
}
```

And also I have form like this for GroupVisitReconfirmation:

```
<g:form action="completeReconfirmation" params="${params.frame ? [frame: '✓'] : [:]}" novalidate="novalidate">
  <fieldset class="form">
    <field:wrapper bean="${bean}" field="visitorsNumber">
      <g:render template="reconfirmation/textField"  />
    </field:wrapper>
  </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

How can I pass in this form GroupVisitRequest? Because when I'm doing it right now I have Null Pointer Exception in constraints.

Comment: I dont see the groupVisistRequest in your form, what do you mean by I am doing it right? Also please post the exception stacktrace